# JavaScript problem with ID name

Tags: javascript

I'm using the below code to hide and show divs

```
function showSubCat(id)
{   for(var i=1; i<=12; i++)
    {   var hideid = 'cat'+i;
        document.getElementById(hideid).style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

The IDs of the div are from cat1 to cat12.
All works good, except for cat11 and cat12, they just dont show.

Any ideas?

SOLVED: Function works, the problem was in the  ending tag.

Thaks.

Comment: That sounds like your parameter is wrong. How are you calling this function?

Comment: Why don't you give them all a similar class, hide the entire class, and then just show the one that you need to? I have a feeling that your current approach may be over-complicating things.

Comment: Where is the code where you SHOW the elements?

Comment: Can you clarify? The code above should hide all the DIVs 1 to 12. They are not made visible by the code above. Is there something missing?

Comment: This is the code that call the function<li onclick="showSubCat('cat1')"><img src="images/cat1.png" alt="" width="86" height="86" /><br />Cat 1</li>

Comment: @ MoarCodePlz He is using pure javascript, and there is no standard function for get by classname in javascript. he will always need to loop.

Comment: @MoarCodePlz: Even with the same class he has to loop over all of the elements. And `getElementByClassName` does not work in IE7 and below.

Comment: The loop is not a problem, i mean yes i can remove it with some jQuery but the problem will remain. It does not show the ID.

Comment: Show some HTML and the calling code. Most certainly an id mismatch somewhere.

Comment: @Amr ElGarhy and @Felix Kling regardless of the loop he will not have to generate class names on the fly and then find them. I have a feeling the problem here is with dynamically creating the ID names.

Comment: Works fine for me. Check your HTML (DIV's ID's)

Comment: nothing wrong with the funciton http://jsfiddle.net/73pmT/

Comment: Created a Fiddle with your code, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/KPuU2/

Comment: Works fine for me.  Tested on Chrome and IE.  Make sure you are calling the function correctly.

Comment: THANKS to all. Just after the DIV id 10, the closing tag was </dVI>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/wRWeK/

works fine....